AWS Transfer Server Default Security Group Error - Terraform
I am using this transfer.tf to create Transfer Family Server in AWS, As per AWS Document, If we use VPC in endpoint_type, We don't need to mention default security group.
resource "aws_transfer_server" "backup_server" {

  endpoint_type = "VPC"

  identity_provider_type = "API_GATEWAY"
  url                    = aws_api_gateway_stage.sftp_gateway.invoke_url
  invocation_role        = aws_iam_role.transfer_identity_provider.arn

  logging_role = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch_logging.arn

  # VPC configuration
  endpoint_details {
    vpc_id     = "vpc-008ef7e599"
    subnet_ids = ["subnet-00da4a42248f", "subnet-02c7f32a000f"]
  }
}

I also confirm that these two subnets are available under this VPC in AWS.
Currently I am using this version in Terraform
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      version = "~> 3.28.0"
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}

But I am getting this error
Error: Error creating Transfer Server: InvalidRequestException: Error calling CreateVpcEndpoint: Unable to find the default security group for 6867594205 in VPC vpc-008ef7e599. Please specify a valid security group in input. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: d2e6-52abb8d7cd30; Proxy: null)


The error message says you don't have a default security group for the VPC. Can you verify that?

you may need to set security_group_ids field of endpoint_details https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/transfer_server#security_group_ids-1

Normally this issue means that you do not have any default security group within your VPC, so the issue you’re facing arises because AWS Transfer Family Server requires a security group to associate with the VPC endpoint when the endpoint_type is set to VPC. Although the AWS documentation might mention that you don’t need to specify a default security group explicitly The Transfer Family server will attempt to locate the default security group within the VPC; if it’s missing or deleted, the server creation fails.
So you can create a SG and attach it to your aws_transfer_server configuration in the endpoint_details
resource "aws_transfer_server" "backup_server" {
  endpoint_type = "VPC"

  identity_provider_type = "API_GATEWAY"
  url                    = aws_api_gateway_stage.sftp_gateway.invoke_url
  invocation_role        = aws_iam_role.transfer_identity_provider.arn

  logging_role = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch_logging.arn

  endpoint_details {
    vpc_id             = "vpc-008ef7e599"
    subnet_ids         = ["subnet-00da4a42248f", "subnet-02c7f32a000f"]
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.transfer_sg.id] #Add your SG
  }
}

